# How can I concatenate column data into string separated by ","?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr1

I have data like this

```
ATTRIBUTE_NAME
--------------
Area
Branch
Sector
Data Line
```

and I need to get data like this

```
Area","Branch","Sector","Data Line
```

OR

```
"Area","Branch","Sector","Data Line"
```

or something simpler. I have tried:

- `WM_CONCAT` but I'm not able to specify the separator
- `LISTAGG` is not supported in my Oracle version
- `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` I'm not sure how to use

I am using Oracle 11.1.0.6

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the extra separators onto the column before the aggregation:

```
select wm_concat('"' || attribute_name || '"')
  from my_table
```

You should note that `WM_CONCAT()` is an unsupported function and it would be better to upgrade your database to at least 11.2 (if not 12) to take advantage of the increased functionality.